# Find identical rows between two xlsx files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I just saw several post but I didn't find a solution.

I am trying to compare 2 Excel files in different workbooks using Pandas in Python.

work1:

```
A     B     C
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
```

work2:

```
A     B     C
1     1     1
2     5     2
3     3     3
```

desire output:

```
A     B     C
1     1     1

3     3     3
```

So far what I've got is:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('/path/work1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('/path/work2.xlsx')

common = df1[df1==df2]
print common
common.to_excel('/path/result.xlsx')
```

But what I get is:

```
A     B     C
1     1     1
2           2
3     3     3
```

The point is that if the column B of work1 has any coincidence with work2, the output should be only the entire row coincidence.

I'm working with NGS variants anotation, so it will be helpful to analyze affected families that the variants is shared.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is write your condition to find *all* columns in a row that are equal. As of now, you generate a mask that is the same shape as the original dataframes, so when you index, you create NaNs instead of filtering like you should.

**Option 1**
Using `eq` + `all` -

```
df1[df1.eq(df2).all(axis=1)]

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
2  3  3  3
```

Keep in mind that pandas auto-aligns dataframes by indices when comparing, so if your dataframes are not identical with respect to the index or columns, this will not work. If that's the case, a little preprocessing is needed.

```
df2.index = df1.index
df2.columns = df1.columns
```

Now, this (as well as the merge) should work.

---

**Option 2**
inner `merge` on all columns -

```
df1.merge(df2)

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  3  3  3
```

Comment: great! Thank you! I tried it with a large file and I took only the first 9 rows. So I copied that in 2 files. And if it is correct should return me all 9 rows, well it returns me only the last 2 and I don't know why. Then I modied one of these and it returns me only 1. So I don't know what could be with the others

Comment: @IgorLopez Check your indices and columns, the issue may lie there.

Comment: @COLDSPEED thanks and forgive me my ignorance with pandas, but if I'm using 2 indentical files how is that possible?

Comment: @IgorLopez Can you copy and paste the dataframes in question into your question so I can take a look at them?

Comment: @IgorLopez If your question wasn't answered, please fix your question with more information about why the answer didn't work. Otherwise, if the answer worked, please mark it accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @COLDSPEED sorry for my late reply but I was out of the office. I tried to index them but it looks ok, and I cannot wirte the dataframe because it's too long (it has 188 columns)

Comment: @WindSur Please try reproducing the problem with a sample. Unless there isn't any problem?